# Strongly-Continuous linear functionals on $\mathcal{B}(H)$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Suppose $H$ is a complex Hilbert space and
$$w: \mathcal{B}(H) \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$$
is a bounded linear functional on $\mathcal{B}(H)$ such that $w$ is continuous even if $\mathcal{B}(H)$ is given the strong operator topology.  I am supposed to prove that there exists $c>0$ and $h_1, \dots, h_n \in H$ such that for all $x \in \mathcal{B}(H)$, one has
$$|w(x)| \leq c \sqrt{\sum_{i = 1}^n \|x(h_i)\|^2}.$$
I have no idea how to begin.  To me, the strong operator topology is given by the family of seminorms
$$\{\|x\|_h = \|x(h)\| : h \in H\}.$$

Comment: Hint: What do the open sets of the strong operator topology look like (specifically, what is a basis for this topology)?  What does this say about $\{x : |w(x)| < 1\}$?

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful.

Comment: @NateEldredge You could post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What do the open sets of the strong operator topology look like (specifically, what is a basis for this topology)? What does this say about $\{x:|w(x)|<1\}$?